# errors with opening URL in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, colorbox, querystringparameter

I have the following asp:HyperLink which opens in ColorBox:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink2" runat="server" Text="Delete" class="example7" ToolTip="Delete this Album" NavigateUrl='<%# "delete_album_confirm.aspx?AlbumName=" & Eval("album_name") & "&PhotoFilename=" & Eval("photo_file_name") & "&AlbumID=" & Eval("album_id")  %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

The above works fine if the `Eval("album_name")` is without space. The problem is when i have spaces the colorBox doesn't open. For example:

```
delete_album_confirm.aspx?AlbumName=testing album cover&PhotoFilename=resized_CIMG1426.jpg&AlbumID=41
```

Can anyone tell me how I can use spaces and still get this working?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably that spaces are not allowed in URLs, so what you would need to is use Url Encoding.  You should be able to accomplish that like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink2" runat="server" Text="Delete" class="example7" ToolTip="Delete this Album" NavigateUrl='<%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode("delete_album_confirm.aspx?AlbumName=" & Eval("album_name") & "&PhotoFilename=" & Eval("photo_file_name") & "&AlbumID=" & Eval("album_id"))  %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I get the following: http://localhost:3478/FPOS_v2/delete_album_confirm.aspx%3fAlbumName%3dtesting+album+cover%26PhotoFilename%3dresized_CIMG1426.jpg%26AlbumID%3d41
 but this doesn't open it delete_album_confirm.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Replace your spaces with the URL encoded equivalent, `%20`.  e.g.

> delete_album_confirm.aspx?AlbumName=testing%20album
>   cover&PhotoFilename=resized_CIMG1426.jpg&AlbumID=41